# windows.onload function not working

Tags: javascript, html

i want to execute two function as soon as my page load , i have used onload in body tag and windows.onload in script but both are not working.
here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>(Type a title for your page here)</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function my_code(){
alert(" Alert inside my_code function");
var text_val = document.getElementById("t2"); 
text_val.select();
}

window.onload=my_code();
</script>

</head>
<body >

<form name=form1 method=post action=''>
<input type=text name=t1 value=plus2net id="t2">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Substitution or addition to code both are accepted , give some link where i get more information.
thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the parenthesis from the onload code.

Comment: This has been asked and answered in multiple forms multiple times. You need to learn the difference between a function reference and a function call.

Answer (score 1):

Changing this :

```
window.onload=my_code();
```

To this should do it:

```
window.onload=my_code;
```

The reason why: `my_code()` causes the function to be executed. Without `()` you are passing the function as a reference to the onload event on the window. The onload event when fired will execute the function.

**Even better** is using the event setter `addEventListener`. When other code (like jQuery or other libraries) use the window.onload, using addEventListener wouldn't cause the onload event to be overwritten.

```
window.addEventListener("load", my_code, false); //you need to omit the "on" when assigning with this method.
```

This is the preferred way.

Comment: What makes you think jQuery uses `window.onload`?

Comment: @torazaburo, I don't think jQuery would do that, however anybody can write a jQuery plugin that (I admit badly coded) could overwrite your window.onload.

Comment: I agree that using `window.onload` is suboptimal. However, any library which hijacks that is a buggy piece of garbage that you should not use anyway.

Comment: @torazaburo: Hallelujah and Amen to that!